# Why does .Fetch() throws an null reference exception?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have the following nhibernate linq query and it throws a null reference exception

```
promotions = (from a in session.Query<Application>()
                          from ap in a.Promotions
                          where a.Id == applicationId
                          && ap.EndDate >= DateTime.Now && ap.StartDate <= DateTime.Now
                          select ap).Fetch(ap => ap.LandingPage).ToList();
```

The same query without the .Fetch() works fine. I am passing the same id both times, so it's not a data issue.

Is this a bug, or by design? How can I make it not throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you move the .Fetch(ap => ap.LandingPage) to immediately after the declaration does that change the outcome?

```
from ap in a.Promotions.Fetch(ap => ap.LandingPage)
```

Comment: Promotions is of type ICollection and Fetch is an extension method of IQueryable, therefore it won't compile

Answer (score 0):

```
from a in session.Query<Application>().Fetch(ap => ap.LandingPage)
//the rest of your code
```

Comment: You do realize that he is selecting items from a child table of a different type, right? In this instance, your param ap would not *have* a child called "LandingPage" because it is on ap.Promotions.